# Use forcetk to get all object prefix or get object name from object id

Tags: javascript, rest-api, forcetk

I am trying to use `forcetk` and I want to know if there is a simple way to:

1. Get all object prefixes for all objects present in org

**OR**

2. Based on an 15 or 18 digit Id get which object does it belong to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `describeGlobal` to get all of the object prefixes and then put them in a map:

```
var prefixToName = {};
client.describeGlobal(function(response){
    for (var i = 0; i < response.sobjects.length; i++) {
        var sobject = response.sobjects[i];
        if (sobject.keyPrefix) {
            prefixToName[sobject.keyPrefix] = sobject.name;
        }
    }
});
```

Then

```
var accountId = '0015000000VALE3';
console.log(accountId + ' has sobject type ' + prefixToName[accountId.substring(0,3)]);
```

Will give you

```
0015000000VALE3 has sobject type Account
```

Comment: Was hoping for an answer from you Pat, thanks for same :)
I checked this out. Do we have a provision to get all fields for an object as well in forcetk? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just checked, I think I need to use normal describe for object "forcetk.Client.prototype.describe" which can help me out. I will try for same.

Comment: Yes - use the per-object describe method to get all the fields.